# Laravel 5.1 session updating randomly

Tags: ajax, session, laravel-5.1

I have one issue regarding session of laravel 5.1. I have written a code which will give 2 ajax call simultaneously. In first ajax call i am retrieving data and inserting paramertes into session. And in the response of first ajax, i am giving second ajax call to only update the session for second ajax parameters. But i am facing problem for session is that, it sometimes updates session and sometime fail to update the session. I am storing these parameters into session because on page reload, i am using these parameters again. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It is often best to supply some code to illustrate what your problem is.

Comment: Can you use the debugging tools your browser has to find out what is being returned by the second ajax request when it fails, I have a feeling this is another ```unauthorized access``` question.

Comment: @Ashley Wrench Actually it is working on my localhost. I am facing problem on live site. And one more thing. When these 2 ajax calls are completed, I am again giving ajax call to retrieve data and update same session variable. But it is also not working.

Comment: @MaheshGaikwad I think its because your making to many requests at once - as you know Laravel requires a token for security - It also stops people from spamming the server (ddos). Laravel is probably rejecting your calls because it looks like your trying to ddos the server with the same token, and if you put the env in Production  it will be less lenient. I think (even if this isn't the fix) you should try to make functions that compress all the data you need into one request, that way you won't have the DDOS issue.

Comment: @Ashley Wrench Thanks for your reply. But only first time i am giving 2 ajax call simultaneously. After that i am only giving one ajax call on autocomplete box click.